# Error mismatched types: expected 'collections::vec::Vec<i32>', found '&collections::vec::Vec<i32>'

Tags: rust, type-mismatch

I'm trying to use `selection_sort` to create a sorted vector while keeping the original unsorted vector:

```
fn main() {
    let vector_1: Vec<i32> = vec![15, 23, 4, 2, 78, 0];
    let sorted_vector = selection_sort(&vector_1);
    println!("{:?} is unsorted, \n{:?} is sorted.", &vector_1, &sorted_vector);
}

fn selection_sort(vector_1: &Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32> {
    let mut vector = vector_1;
    let start = 0;
    while start != vector.len() {
        for index in (start .. vector.len()) {
            match vector[index] < vector[start] {
                true  => vector.swap(index, start),
                false => println!("false"), // do nothing
            }
        }
        start += 1;
    }
    vector
}
```

Error:

```
   Compiling selection_sort v0.1.0 (file:///home/ranj/Desktop/Rust/algorithms/sorting/selection_sort)
src/main.rs:21:5: 21:11 error: mismatched types:
 expected `collections::vec::Vec<i32>`,
    found `&collections::vec::Vec<i32>`
(expected struct `collections::vec::Vec`,
found &-ptr) [E0308]
src/main.rs:21     vector
                   ^~~~~~
src/main.rs:21:5: 21:11 help: run `rustc --explain E0308` to see a detailed explanation
error: aborting due to previous error
Could not compile `selection_sort`.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your question can be simplified to this (please review and follow how to create an [MCVE](/help/mcve) when asking questions here):

```
fn selection_sort(vector: &Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32> {
    vector
}
```

You are accepting a reference to a type and trying to return it as not-a-reference. That simply is a straight-forward type error, the same as this:

```
fn something(value: &u8) -> u8 {
    value
}
```

`T` and `&T` are different types.

Ultimately, your code doesn't make sense right now. To make a `&Vec<T>` into a `Vec<T>`, you'd need to clone it:

```
fn selection_sort(vector: &Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32> {
    let mut vector = vector.clone();
    let mut start = 0;
    while start != vector.len() {
        for index in (start .. vector.len()) {
            match vector[index] < vector[start] {
                true  => vector.swap(index, start),
                false => println!("false"), // do nothing
            }
        }
        start += 1;
    }
    vector
}
```

But 99.99% of the time, it doesn't make sense to accept a `&Vec<T>`; accept a `&[T]` instead:

```
fn selection_sort(vector: &[i32]) -> Vec<i32> {
    let mut vector = vector.to_vec();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: That would have saved me a lot of typing.. anyway I do understand that the two are different types, but I don't understand how to copy its values

Comment: So if I understand you right, it is better to use a reference slice of a vector than a reference to vector. Is making a slice of a vector not an extra calculation? if i'm right using a reference vector vs reference slice take the same amount of memory

Comment: Creating a slice from a reference to vector is very cheap to do. The slice is a direct pointer to the data, the `&Vec` has an extra indirection for the function accepting it.

Comment: Thank you both, your responses are very useful

Comment: Actually, a `&[T]` [takes more space](http://is.gd/5CnV4X) than a `&Vec<T>`. Technically, I do suppose it's a *tiny* bit more of a calculation, but it's more accepting of various types (`Vec` and arrays, to name two).